# I want my binded DataGrid to NOT sort the ItemsSource too

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, datagrid

I have a `DataGrid` which I bound to a `ObservableCollection` via the `ItemsSource`-Property. This DataGrid is `IsReadOnly="True"` and `AutoGenerateColumns="False"`. (Columns were added in the XAML)

So far everything works, **but**:
When i sort a by a column, the ItemsSource gets sorted, too. I want the user to be able to sort the columns **without** the actual `ItemsSource` being sorted too.

Is that possible and if so how do i manage that?

**Edit:**
Problem should be reproducable with this. When you click on *Number*-header, the `ComboBox` items have the same new order as the `DataGrid`.

XAML of MainWindow:

```
<DockPanel LastChildFill="True">
    <ComboBox DockPanel.Dock="Bottom" Name="cbItems" IsEditable="True"/>
    <DataGrid Name="dataGrid" AutoGenerateColumns="False" IsReadOnly="True">
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Name}" Header="Name"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding SomeNumber}" Header="SomeNumber"/>
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
</DockPanel>
```

Code:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    ObservableCollection<Item> ItemList;

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        ItemList = new ObservableCollection<Item>();

        Random rnd = new Random();
        for(int i = 0; i < 15; i++)
            ItemList.Add(new Item("blabla" + rnd.Next(10, 100), rnd.Next(10000, 100000)));

        dataGrid.ItemsSource = ItemList;
        cbItems.ItemsSource = ItemList;
    }
}

public class Item
{
    private string name;
    private int number;

    public Item(string name, int number)
    {
        this.name = name;
        this.number = number;
    }

    public string Name { get { return name; } set { name = value; } }
    public int SomeNumber { get { return number; } set { number = value; } }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return name;
    }
}
```

Comment: By default, the source collection does *not* get sorted when you sort the DataGrid. Why do you think that the source collection gets sorted?

Comment: On my Main Window I have a ComboBox which is bound to the same ObservableCollection. The items in there get ordered the same when i sort by a column in the DataGrid

Comment: Post your code if you want anyone to be able to tell you what you are doing wrong: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: I don't know what code to post, because i don't have the slightest clue where the problem lies myself. The entire project is over 1000 of lines...

Comment: I just went throug with the debugger single-step to the point my window with the DataGrid is open and loaded. When i click on a column header the DataGrid and the ComboBox on my MainWindow get sorted, without the debugger going anywhere in my code.

Comment: @mm8 Yes. And i think you read that i don't have a clue where the problem is in my code? "The more code there is to go through, the less likely people can find your problem"  I don't want to post 1000s of lines. I could upload my entire project, I just think that noone is going to help me then either.

Comment: @mm8 I edited my question to contain minimal code which still reproduces my problem. Is it okay like this?

Comment: Although the `DataGrid` is not reordering the source collection, it may be sorting the _default collection view_, which is shared between items controls.  That would explain why the `ComboBox` also appears sorted. 
 A simple solution would be to clone the collection, or manually wrap either `ItemsSource` in a collection view.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to overcome the fact both controls will reference the same collection view by setting the `ItemsSource` properties to two independant views:

```
dataGrid.ItemsSource = new ListCollectionView(ItemList);
cbItems.ItemsSource = new ListCollectionView(ItemList);
```

Comment: Thank you, also for your patience. I didn't even know `ListCollectionView` were a thing. Today i learned...

Answer (score 0):

I have just had the exact same problem, which was solved by using OrderBy as follows:

cbItems.ItemsSource = ItemList.OrderBy(Item => Item.Name)